# Accessing other app's permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to make an app which will get the names of the apps in the same android phone but also I want to access the permissions of those apps. Is it possible to make that in-app without going to settings?

Comment: What does "access the permissions of those apps" mean? Do you mean "find out what permissions those apps use"?

Comment: how you will manage to see what permissions other apps uses? the code of the apps are encrypted..

Comment: @IDroid: The code of the apps are not encrypted, and information about the permissions held by each app is available via `PackageManager`.

Comment: i thinked that if you put the minifyEnabled to true , you cant see the code from other apps that are in release

Comment: Yes, I mean that @CommonsWare

Comment: @IDroid: That obfuscates the names of fields, classes, methods, etc. It does not encrypt the code. It also has no impact on manifest entries, which is where `<uses-permission>` elements lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to find the permissions requested by apps, you can use `PackageManager` for that. [`PackageInfo` has `requestedPermissions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#requestedPermissions) to list the permissions requested via `<uses-permission>` elements. [`getInstalledPackages()` on `PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)) can give you the `List<PackageInfo>` to work from.